# Smarty problems

Tags: smarty

I'm having trouble with using my php/pdo script built on smarty framework at server I have DirectAdmin installed. To test whether its the problem in my script or anything else, I also tried to install it into my another server with zpanel installed and it worked without any problems.

I have enabled the php error reporting and also enabled smarty install test and found no errors with all tests OK.

The server on which I'm having problems has following configs:

> Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU 5150 @ 2.66GHz,  8GB RAM,  CentOS 6.0
>   64-Bit,  Apache/2.2.27 (Unix),  PHP Version 5.5.13,  Direct Admin
>   1.45.2

Also, this server is dedicated server(with DirectAdmin installed, smarty not working), while others I have are VPS(with zPanel installed, smarty working).

It is actually not displaying the smarty template which is included within one tpl file that is being displayed. (The included file is through the syntax `{include file="header.tpl"}` ) And this is actually not working on the server with DirectAdmin installed, while it works on servers I have zpanel and cpanel.

Comment: You should provide more details to the question. What are those Smarty problems from title? DirectAdmin have nothing in common with Smarty. You should simple download only Smarty lib and create sample test script to check what the problem is.

Comment: It is actually not displaying the smarty template which is included within one tpl file that is being displayed. (The included file is through the syntax {include file="header.php"} ) And this is actually not working on the server with DirectAdmin installed, while it works on servers I have zpanel and cpanel.

Comment: Also, there are no errors neither php nor of smarty, as I already checked through enabling php error reporting and also the smarty install test function.

Comment: I don't know what you try to achieve but include is for including Template files not PHP files. Have you turned on error reporting? Without examples from your code it rather won't be possible to help you

Comment: Sorry for that mistake in comment, I actually included the tpl file in a tpl file, not the php file.

it is how my code is for home.tpl (that is displayed for index page)

{include file='header.tpl'}
<!-- Home Page content here -->
{include file='footer.tpl'}

The essence of my question is that if this same code and whole my script is working on other servers having zpanel and cpanel control panels, why is it not working on server I have with directadmin control panel, that's the point I am questioning.

Comment: You need to finally understand Directadmin has nothing in common with Smarty. That's for 99% not Directadmin fault that your script doesn't work on that server. It's rather this server settings or your bad code but without errors and details noone will help you

Comment: as far as i know, smarty is not dependent to the admin interface. Check if your templates_c { and maby cache dir } has write permission by apache user.

Comment: In which folder is your heder.tpl? You need full path like: {include file="themes/mytheme/header.tpl"}